# how to add users into a specific group in active directory based on the user selection type powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working a script to add user to a specific group at the moment user gets created as a normal domain user but i am not sure how to add a user to an admin group of tester group.Also how to check if user doesnot enter first name i should prompt user to enter first name I am  using the following script

```
$NewUser = Read-Host "New Username"
$firstname = Read-Host "First Name"
$Lastname = Read-Host "Last Name"
$NewName = "$firstname $lastname"


New-ADUser -SamAccountName $NewUser -Name $NewName -GivenName $firstname -Surname  
$lastname -displayname  $Newname -UserPrincipalName $firstname@handmade.local -Path   
"CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 
"Password" -Force)  -Enabled $true

write-host "!!!New User"$NewUser "Created!!!"
```

I am getting the following error:
when I run this script

```
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $NewUser -Name $NewName -GivenName $FirstName -Surname   
$LastName -displayname  $NewName -UserPrincipalName $FirstName@mydomain.local -Path 
"CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=local" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 
"password" -Force)  -Enabled $true 


$h = @{1="Dev";2="Admins"}
 Write-Host "Please select:"
 $h.getEnumerator() |sort | % {
Write-Host ([string]$_.Name +". " + $_.Value)
} 
Write-Host
[string]$g = Read-Host -Prompt "Select group number or numbers, coma separated"

$groups = $g -split ","

foreach($group in $groups){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $h[$group] -Members $NewUser
} 


write-host "!!!New User"$NewUser "Created!!!"
exit 0
 }

}
```

Error:
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument
and try the command again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\add user to AD.ps1:60 char:33
+     Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $h[$group] -Members $NewUser

I am selecting the groups as 1,2

Comment: What do you mean by _"admin group of tester group"_? You can use `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GroupName -Members $NewUser` to add new user to a given group.

Comment: hey Raf thanks for the reply, i meant to Say if i have two groups say Admin group and Tester group how can i modify my script so i should have an option to select group and based on input the new user is saved in that group

Comment: @Raf by using the above code i can specify the Admin group and the user does get created in Admin group, however what if i have 3 to 4 groups and i would like to display those groups and i would like to user to enter the group name so that new user gets created in that group or groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has done the job for me.

```
$h = @{1="Dev";2="Admins"}
Write-Host "Please select:"
$h.getEnumerator() |sort | % {
Write-Host ([string]$_.Name +". " + $_.Value)
} 
Write-Host
[string] $g = Read-Host -Prompt "Select group number or numbers, coma separated"

$groups = $g -split ","

foreach($group in $groups){
[int32] $no = $group

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $h.item($no) -Members $NewUser
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - groups and their corresponding number choice mappings are defined in `$h`. When prompted enter coma separated values ie. `1` or `2,3`

```powershell
$h = @{1="group1";2="group2";3="group"}
Write-Host "Please select:"
$h.getEnumerator() |sort | % {
    Write-Host ([string]$_.Name +". " + $_.Value)
} 
Write-Host
[string]$g = Read-Host -Prompt "Select group number or numbers, coma separated"

$groups = $g -split ","

foreach($group in $groups){
    $group_to_add = [string]($h[$group])
    Write-Host "Adding $NewUser to $group_to_add"
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group_to_add -Members $NewUser
}
```

Comment: hi Raf i have used the above script but getting some validation error , i have modified the question

Comment: Amended the answer to cast the hash element as string.

Comment: now i am getting this error Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=mydomain,DC=local'.

Comment: Hi raf as soon as i select the option for groups e.g 1 or 1,2 i get this error now i am getting this error Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: 'DC=mydomain,DC=local'

Comment: Added little debug, see what happens now. I take it you can run `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity Dev -Members $NewUser` ok? What PS version are you on?(works on 4)

Comment: i am using ps version 3.0 and yes it does work if i simply specify group name in -identity but its not working where user has to make a selection between different available groups

Comment: what does the out say now(with `write-host` there should be an extra line)?